# How to refresh the multi-language controls for each view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

**I need to do multiple language switching within the app**

1. Need to stay in the current view after switching the language
2. And my entire application UI needs to be updated to see the replaced language

**I found that many people's approach is to reset the root view, which means that you want to re-create the view, the data need to re-request, etc.**

**I think this is very unreasonable**

Do not you use Notification, is there any other way?

If there is a valid link and demo reference is even better

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure on how your app works, but why don't you just try something like this:

```
func updateLanguage() {}
```

You can use dictionaries to help you to easily update your content. I've made a simple example so you can understand what I'm talking about:

```
enum Languages {
    case english
    case portuguese
}

var myLabel = UILabel()

let myLabelText : [Languages : String] = [
    Languages.english : "My Label",
    Languages.portuguese : "Minha Etiqueta"
]

func updateLanguage(to language : Languages) {
    // Updates myLabel's text in real time:
    myLabel.text = myLabelText[language]
    // Update other UI elements below...
}
```

Whenever you call the method "updateLanguage", your UI elements will change it's text value in real time, no need to reload anything or to use another "hacks", it's pretty simple and straightforward, I have this approach on my apps, and it just works.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This approach is relatively simple, if so, every page I need to call updateLanguage this method, there is a better way?

I need the method can be used throughout the program, including UIButton, UILabel, NavigationItem, TabBarItem, etc.

thank you for your help

Comment: @Snow You will only need to call this method when the user changes language. If you have multiple view controllers, it's better to have a updateLanguage method for each one! Inside the method you can update whatever UI element you want, UIButtons, UILabels, anything, as long as you have a reference for them!

Comment: I don't deny that this is a viable way

But a number of controllers have such a way to re-set the language, in the back of the page when the language is also set to notify the previous page update

How do you notify each page? I do not think this is an efficient way

Comment: @Snow You don't need to update every page, just the one that's being used. However, when the user switches page, then you will need to update those ones when that happens. If you want to update every single page, even the ones that aren't being used (and might not ever be used), you will need something like a global updateLanguage method, but that's computationally much more intensive and way less efficient. Again, I don't know how your app works, but that would be my approach any day!

Answer (score 0):

Try  loadView() to refresh same view controller. And add same method in other vc's viewwillappear from which u have pushed that vc .